# removing default styling from css in blazor web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have having some trouble removing the default styling applied by blazor when I am creating a new page. I have a simple landing page that has to have the "About" header that is applied from the MainLayout.razor page removed, as well as the styling from the app.razor.css style sheet needs to be removed.

That app.css seems to be adding some padding/margin on my page. I still want the nav menu to be seen when I navigate to this page, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it work. I have tried creating a custom Layout in the layout folder but I can't use the @using directive properly in the Client folder.

I can't access my server folders/files from the client razor page I have created with the @using directive for some reason.

Is there a simple way to do this I am not seeing? I have looked in the Microsoft documentation under layout, but it seems the way my project is setup with client/server that I am running into a few hurdles.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't remove `<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />` from App.razor work?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Bootstrap styling, delete `wwwroot/bootstrap`, along with the following line from `Components/App.razor`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

To delete the app styling, delete everything in `wwwroot/app.css` (you might want to leave the `.blazor-error-boundary` lines). You could also remove the link tag for that in `Components/App.razor` too, but you'll probably want to add your own CSS to the file instead.

Finally, make sure you perform a hard refresh in your browser. This was the bit that got me, and I'm actually surprised it's required.

Comment: I actually just wanted to remove it for specifically that page though, I did a work around of commenting out one of the style pages as well as over-writing some of the other styling with inline css/using my own css page